# Why telephone lines use -48V not +48V? What’s the difference practically in -ve and +ve voltages?

Tags: telephone

Why telephone lines use -48V not +48V? What’s the difference practically in -ve and +ve voltages?
Detailed answer would be appreciated.

Comment: http://mathscinotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/positiveground.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathodic_protection#Impressed_current_systems  It is an example of cathodic protection of the wires to make the most positive voltage inside the building to earth ground where the corrosion can be easily managed and the extensive -48V wire network protected.

Comment: @Rumi. Why did you post this on Aviation.SE? Aircraft never used landline telephones!